# Безопасный способ передачи пароля от клиента до ключевого контейнера

Tags: безопасность, ssl, openssl, pkcs#12, pkcs#11

Делаю реализацию сервиса цифровой подписи. Ключевой контейнер в моем случае будет находится на сервере, зашифрованный парольной фразой. Можно ли передать эту фразу в зашифрованном виде прямо в `openssl`. Цель в том чтоб пароль не возможно было восстановить, если перехватить его на любом месте от браузера до криптопровайдера.

Comment: Именно для этого были придуманы асимметричные схемы шифрования. Клиент генерирует у себя приватный ключ RSA, передаёт вам публичный ключ. Вы шифруете публичным ключом всё, что вам нужно и отсылаете клиенту. Он у себя расшифровывает своим приватным. Погуглите [openssl rsa encrypt with public key](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+rsa+encrypt+with+public+key). Мне понравилась [вторая ссылка](https://www.czeskis.com/random/openssl-encrypt-file.html), всё по делу, никакой воды.

Comment: шифровать мы умеем. можно ли шифровать так чтоб не осталось пароля в открытом виде в памяти сервера совсем

Comment: Если вы не контролируете сервер, то никаких гарантий.

Comment: сервер то контролирую, но думаю как исключить атаку на него.